# Nginx com Erro de conexão SSL

Tags: nginx

Criei um certificado SSL para testar no servidor e configurei no Nginx da seguinte forma:

```
# HTTPS server
#
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name kriaki.com.br;

    root /home/ubuntu/public_kriaki;
    index index.html index.htm;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/kriaki.com.br.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/kriaki.com.br.key;
#
#   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
#
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#   ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
#   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
}
```

Salvei e utilizei o seguinte comando para checar se esta tudo ok:

```
sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

E tudo ok. Reiniciei o Nginx, e fui acessar a url com `https://` e o navegador retorna o erro: `Código de erro: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Será que o erro está no certificado? Mas fiz ele como sempre faço:

```
sudo openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout kriaki.com.br.key -out kriaki.com.br.csr
sudo openssl x509 -in kriaki.com.br.csr -out kriaki.com.br.cert -req -signkey kriaki.com.br.key -days 30
```

O que poderia ser?

Comment: Resolvi aqui, no arquivo de configuração `default` eu tinha habilitado outro certificado e por algum motivo deu conflito. Tenho outros dominios no servidor que quando acesso eles em `https://` eles tentam acessar o certificado que pus ali em cima que é especifico daquele dominio. Deixei `server_name`  claro para `kriaki.com.br`, porque os outros dominios estão carregando também o mesmo certificado de kriaki.com.br?

Comment: Gilson, responda sua própria pergunta, e descreva em detalhes como conseguiu. Depois de dois dias marque ela como certo

Answer (score 2):

Como eu estava testanto configurações no nginx, no arquivo de configuração `default` que fica em `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` já tinha uma configuração para ssl para outro dominio.   Provavelmente com os dois juntos e a caracteristica de ssl de um ip por ssl, eles estavam dando esses erro de ssl ao acessar. Somente deixei um e funciona normal. Mas como eu estava necessitando somente de um dominio com ssl deixei assim mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Você ainda pode criar um bloco de server para cada domínio com certificado que você tiver...

Você tem necessidade de declarar

`ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;` ?

Isso pode causar erros com clientes que usam outros tipos de ciphers.

Comment: Na verdade essa linha esta ali, mas não está ativa, note que tem um `#` na frente.

Comment: Voce citou `bloco de server`, mas isso se eu tiver um ip dedicado para cada certificado correto?